# How to save & append to a serialized MessagePack binary file in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, msgpack

I'm trying to use `MessagePack` to save multiple lists of structs because I read that its performance is better than `BinaryFormatter` serialization.

What I want to do is to receive real-time time series data and to regularly save(append) it to disk time to time, for example, if the number of elements of a list is 100. My questions are:

1) Is it better to serialize lists of structs and save it to disk asynchronously in this scenario?

2) How to simply save it to disk with MessagePack?

```
public struct struct_realTime
{
    public int indexNum { get; set; }
    public string currentTime { get; set; }
    public string currentType { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<struct_realTime> list_temp = new List<struct_realTime>(100000);

        for (int num=0; num < 100000; num++)
        {
            list_temp.Add(new struct_realTime
            {
                indexNum = 1,
                currentTime = "time",
                currentType = "type",
            });
        }

        string filename = "file.bin";

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            byte[] bytes = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(list_temp);
            Console.WriteLine(MessagePackSerializer.ToJson(bytes));
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it creates `file.bin` and prints out 100000 structs, but the file is 0 byte.

When I use `BinaryFormatter`, I do this:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Append))
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(fileStream, list_temp);
}
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: why do you want to append a binary file?  Make no sense.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not a programmer, so please understand me! I want to receive data and save it to disk continuously. I used to use just text files but someone here told me that binary files are better in terms of performance. But I don't want to make multiple binary files, and that's how I've reached this question. Could you recommend me any other ways to do this?

Comment: The issue is retrieving the data.  Just putting binary filers continuously into a file you probably can't remove the data later.  Unless each file contains a size you will not be able to get the data later.

Comment: For reasons not to use `BinaryFormatter` for this purpose (or any other) see [What are the deficiencies of the built-in BinaryFormatter based .Net serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/703073/3744182).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to *append* an object (here `List<struct_realTime>`) serialized using [`MessagePackSerializer`](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp) to a file containing an already-serialized sequence of similar objects, in the same way it is possible with [`BinaryFormatter`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/803600/3744182), [protobuf-net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15265698/3744182) or [Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44787652/3744182).  Later, you presumably want to be able to deserialize the entire sequence into a list or array of objects of the same type.

Your code has three problems, two simple and one fundamental.

The simple problems are as follows:

- You don't actually write to the `fileStream`.  Instead, do the following:

  ```
  // Append each list_temp sequentially
  using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
  {
      MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, list_temp);
  }
  ```
- You haven't marked `struct_realTime` with [`[MessagePackObject]` attributes](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp#object-serialization).  This can be implemented e.g. as follows:

  ```
  [MessagePackObject]
  public struct struct_realTime
  {
      [Key(0)]
      public int indexNum { get; set; }
      [Key(1)]
      public string currentTime { get; set; }
      [Key(2)]
      public string currentType { get; set; }
  }
  ```

Having done that, you can now repeatedly serialize `list_temp` to a file... but you will not be able to read them afterwards!  That's because `MessagePackSerializer` seems to read the *entire file* when deserializing the root object, skipping over any additional data appended in the file.  Thus code like the following will fail, because only one object gets read from the file:

```
List<List<struct_realTime>> allItemsInFile = new List<List<struct_realTime>>();
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    while (fileStream.Position < fileStream.Length)
    {
        allItemsInFile.Add(MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<List<struct_realTime>>(fileStream));                   
    }
}
Assert.IsTrue(allItemsInFile.Count == expectedNumberOfRootItemsInFile);
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SFtouD).

And code like the following will fail because the (first) root object in the stream is not an array of arrays of objects, but rather just a single array:

```
List<List<struct_realTime>> allItemsInFile;
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    allItemsInFile = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<struct_realTime>>>(fileStream);
}
Assert.IsTrue(allItemsInFile.Count == expectedNumberOfRootItemsInFile);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2AaR0w).

As `MessagePackSerializer` seems to lack the ability to deserialize multiple root objects from a stream, what are your options?  Firstly, you could deserialize a `List<List<struct_realTime>>`, append to it, and then serialize the entire thing back to the file.  Presumably you don't want to do that for performance reasons.

Secondly, using the [MessagePack specification](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md) directly, you could manually seek to the beginning of the file to parse and rewrite an appropriate [`array 32` format header](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md#array-format-family), then seek to the end of the file and use `MessagePackSerializer` to serialize and append the new item.  The following extension method does the job:

```
public static class MessagePackExtensions
{
    const byte Array32 = 0xdd;
    const int Array32HeaderLength = 5;

    public static void AppendToFile<T>(Stream stream, T item)
    {
        if (stream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream));
        if (!stream.CanSeek)
            throw new ArgumentException("!stream.CanSeek");

        stream.Position = 0;
        var buffer = new byte[Array32HeaderLength];
        var read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, Array32HeaderLength);
        stream.Position = 0;
        if (read == 0)
        {
            FormatArray32Header(buffer, 1);
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, Array32HeaderLength);
        }
        else
        {
            var count = ParseArray32Header(buffer, read);
            FormatArray32Header(buffer, count + 1);
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, Array32HeaderLength);
        }

        stream.Position = stream.Length;
        MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(stream, item);
    }

    static void FormatArray32Header(byte [] buffer, uint value)
    {
        buffer[0] = Array32;
        buffer[1] = unchecked((byte)(value >> 24));
        buffer[2] = unchecked((byte)(value >> 16));
        buffer[3] = unchecked((byte)(value >> 8));
        buffer[4] = unchecked((byte)value);
    }

    static uint ParseArray32Header(byte [] buffer, int readCount)
    {
        if (readCount < 5 || buffer[0] != Array32)
            throw new ArgumentException("Stream was not positioned on an Array32 header.");
        int i = 1;
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241060/how-to-get-little-endian-data-from-big-endian-in-c-sharp-using-bitconverter-toin
        //https://stackoverflow.com/a/8241127 by https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell
        var value = unchecked((uint)((buffer[i++] << 24) | (buffer[i++] << 16) | (buffer[i++] << 8) | buffer[i++]));
        return value;
    }
}
```

It can be used to append your `list_temp` as follows:

```
// Append each entry sequentially
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    MessagePackExtensions.AppendToFile(fileStream, list_temp);
}
```

And then later, to deserialize the entire file, do:

```
List<List<struct_realTime>> allItemsInFile;
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    allItemsInFile = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<struct_realTime>>>(fileStream);
}
```

Notes:

- The MessagePack protocol has 3 different array formats:

  - `fixarray` stores an array whose length is up to 15 elements.
  - `array 16` stores an array whose length is up to (2^16)-1 elements.
  - `array 32` stores an array whose length is up to (2^32)-1 elements.

  The extension method requires that the root array be `array 32` to eliminate the need to reformat the entire array when the new size becomes larger than the capacity of `fixarray` or `array 16`.  `MessagePackSerializer`, however, will always write to the most compact format, so appending to a collection previously serialized by `MessagePackSerializer` isn't guaranteed to work.
- If you want to use a fast binary serializer that doesn't require an array count or size at the beginning of the file, thereby supporting append operations out of the box, consider [protobuf-net](/questions/tagged/protobuf-net).  For details see *[I have a Single File And need to serialize multiple objects randomly. How can I in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/817641/3744182)* and *[How to append object to a file while serializing using c# protobuf-net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15265698/3744182)*.

  For a general overview of how to use this serializer see https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net#protobuf-net and *[Protobuf-net: the unofficial manual](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/642677/Protobuf-net-the-unofficial-manual)*.  You will need to mark your types with attributes similar to those of `MessagePackSerializer`.

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yogc3k).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation and code! I've learned a lot from you! Thank you again!